# Is using pointer offsets faster than decrementing in assembler?

Tags: optimization, assembly, x86-64

Do pointer offsets take any extra time?  Which is preferable?

```
mov rcx, length
dec rcx
mov rax, qword ptr [rsi+rcx*8]
```

or

```
mov rcx, length
mov rax, qword ptr [rsi+rcx*8-8]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using an offest should be preferred, on a modern architecture this can be faster, but never slower.

- It is one instruction less. Instruction decoding is a limited resource.
- The length of the code sequence is one byte shorter, becuase the offset is in the char range. This needs less cache memory.
- The dependency chain is one instruction shorter. In your first sequence the address calculationj hast to wait for the result of the decrement.
- Address calculation is done in separate units. There is no speed penalty when using complex addressing modes.

On the other hand there is a chance the the decrement will be reordered to be executed earlier, so that is won't make a difference speed wise.
See more background information at http://www.agner.org/optimize/#manuals .

Comment: +1 for that OTOH comment.  It's been a long time since assembler code and actual order of instruction execution were identical.